# List of string type in C#

Tags: c#

I have a list

```
    List<string> ParamValues = new List<string>();
    ParamValues.Add(txtEmployeeId.Text);
    ParamValues.Add(txtPassword.Text)
```

in a Login.aspx.cs file.

I want to use this list as a parameter of a method. The method is in a DataAccess.cs class file.
How can i do it?

Comment: what's the name of the method you want to use in the DataAccess class?

Answer (score 1):

If method is

```
public void MyMethods(System.Collections.Generic.List<string> paramValue)
{
 //Write your code here
}
```

Call  it

```
DataAcess da= new DataAcess();
 da.MyMethods(ParamValue)
```

in your web page

Comment: I'm surprised this answer got a vote as it doesn't answer the question. It shows how to *declare* a method, but the OP is asking how to *call* an existing method.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the method is declared to *take* a `List<string>` (or an `IList<string>` etc) you would simply call the method using the `ParamValues` variable as your argument:

Calling a static method:

```
DataAccess.SomeMethod(ParamValues);
```

Calling an instance method:

```
DataAccess data = new DataAccess();
data.SomeMethod(ParamValues);
```

(I would rename the variable, by the way - it's unusual to see C# variables in PascalCase.)

Now if you've *actually* got something like this:

```
public void SomeMethod(string id, string password)
```

and you want to call the method filling in one argument for each parameter, then you'll need to use reflection to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You jast pass this list as a parameter as you would do with a normal variable.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of string type

```
List<string> paramValues = new List<string>();
```

Add strings to the list and pass to DBAccess method.

Answer (score 0):

have the method in the DataAccess.cs file take in a list as a parameter.


   `public void MyMethod(List list)
   {
   }`